# How do I polyfill an attribute in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

Given an attribute on an event that will be browser prefixed, I'd like to create a polyfill that makes it appear unprefixed.

E.g. the interface `FooEvent` has an attribute `webkitBar` that I'd like to make appear as just `bar` so that handlers could be written as `onFoo = function(e) { console.log(e.bar); }`

My clumsy initial guess is to inject something into the prototype `FooEvent.prototype.getBar = function() { return this.webkitBar; }`. But, I'm not certain how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES5 only (and IE8)

```
Object.defineProperty(FooEvent.prototype, "bar", {
  get: function () {
    return this.webkitBar;
  },
  configurable: true
});
```

Be warned that extending host objects. (`FooEvent` is a host object) has unknown side effects and is a big bag of undefined behaviour.

I'd recommend static wrappers

```
var eventUtil = {
  getBar: function (ev) {
    return ev.webkitBar;
  }
}

function handler (e) {
  var bar = eventUtil.getBar(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could register a "first" handler to the event to do the transformation:

```
function adaptsBar(e) {
  e.bar = e.webkitBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good resource to get you started.

http://addyosmani.com/blog/writing-polyfills/